# Objects (Including Camera) are aligning themselves to displaced mesh

Tags: modeling

Here is my issue.

I have a displaced mesh. The displacement has been applied and there are no other modifiers.

I was trying to set up the camera for a close-up of displacement, but as soon as I bring the camera towards the mesh, it starts twisting around and trying to align itself to the surface of the mesh, rather than just passing through it.

I dropped in a cube and dragged it toward the mesh, and same thing... the cube tries to align itself (oddly) to the mesh.

I created the displacement many months ago and at that time, I aligned a bunch of low poly building to it; so I am certain that a setting I changed to make the alignment easier is the cause... but I can't remember the setting!

Any help folks can provide is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I figured it out. I had snapping turned on and didn't realize it. I generally don't use it, but when placing the buildings, I must have turned it on to get them aligned to the terrain.